# How to solve the inverse function of $f(x) = x^a + x^b$

Tags: calculus

I don't even know where to start. I have tried everything. I even googled it.

Comment: For one, it won't necessarily exist, since polynomials aren't all injective. And secondly, not all polynomials have (explicit) solutions. In particular, the solution (in terms of $x$) to $x^a + x^b - y = 0$ may not have a closed form.

Comment: Take $a=b=2$, then $f(x)=2x^2$, which is not an injective function.

Comment: you can do it locally... "implicit function theorem" is what you should read about. what do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

As the question is currently phrased, there is no single answer because it depends on the value of $a$ and $b$. There are a few things that can go wrong.

**Injectiveness:** If we have something like $a=b=2$ as mentioned in the comments, the function is not injective and hence will not have an inverse function.

**No closed form:** If we choose $a=5$ and $b=1$ then we have $y=x^5+x$. This is clearly monotone increasing so we know that *there exists* an inverse function. However, finding it is a completely different matter and it turns out (for this particular example) that there is no way of [finding a closed form in radicals and the usual operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).